# mejorar performance de app web react

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo una app donde cargo imagenes y videos de una api pero la herramienta de google PageSpeed Insights
 me da un puntaje muy bajo en movil (65) pero 97 en web, como podria mejorar esto?
dejo capturas de los resultados.
PD: hay código que me esta bloqueando la carga del html y necesito mejorar esto, ¿hay alguna forma de cargar despues este código y hacer mas rapida la carga del html?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia y casi que basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Puede variar mucho, y sin el codigo de tu app es muy dificil ayudarte.